"Never mistake motionless for inactivity" quote from NCIS LA
A few days ago I heard this quote from Hetty on TV:

Never mistake motionless for inactivity, Mr. Callen. Crocodiles get most of their meals that way.

I have been googling around but I couldn't find much information, all I got was the exact original quote (I heard it in Spanish). I also searched in IMDb but there is no reference to it.
Does anyone know which episode is it from?

You are wondering in which episode Hetty says this?

@Paulster2: yes. I've just edited "chapter" to "episode"

If you watched it on TV a few days ago, can't you consult your TV guide or the channel's website to see what episode that was? Or maybe see what episode is aired next to get a rough time frame of it (assuming episodes are aired sequentially).

@SonnyBurnett: Good point. I am not a regular watcher of NCIS, and they broadcast several epsiodes in a row. It might be season 3, and probably episodes between 12 and 18. By the way some broadcasters only show their guide information for the current day and future days. I looked on channel's web, which fortunately also shows past days.

According to TV.com, among various online sources, this quote is taken from episode 12 in season 3 ("The Watchers").

You taught me a new place, looks like IMDb need some update :)

Liked it better when it was called TV Tome, though (god I feel old)
